# Pandas DataFrame RangeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have created a Pandas DataFrame. I need to create a RangeIndex for the DataFrame that corresponds to the frame -
`RangeIndex(start=0, stop=x, step=y)` - where `x` and `y` relate to my DataFrame.

I've not seen an example of how to do this - is there a method or syntax specific to this?

thanks

Comment: it's pretty self explanatory what are you confused by?

Comment: `df.index = range(0, x, y)` should work? Or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 12):

It seems you need `RangeIndex` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : range(1, 21)})
print (df)
     A
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
6    7
7    8
8    9
9   10
10  11
11  12
12  13
13  14
14  15
15  16
16  17
17  18
18  19
19  20


print (df.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=20, step=1)
```

---

```
df.index = pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=99, step=5)
print (df)
     A
0    1
5    2
10   3
15   4
20   5
25   6
30   7
35   8
40   9
45  10
50  11
55  12
60  13
65  14
70  15
75  16
80  17
85  18
90  19
95  20

print (df.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=99, step=5)
```

More dynamic solution:

```
step = 10
df.index = pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=len(df.index) * step - 1, step=step)
print (df)
      A
0     1
10    2
20    3
30    4
40    5
50    6
60    7
70    8
80    9
90   10
100  11
110  12
120  13
130  14
140  15
150  16
160  17
170  18
180  19
190  20

print (df.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=199, step=10)
```

EDIT:

As @ZakS pointed in comments better is use only `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : range(1, 21)}, index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=99, step=5))
print (df)
0    1
5    2
10   3
15   4
20   5
25   6
30   7
35   8
40   9
45  10
50  11
55  12
60  13
65  14
70  15
75  16
80  17
85  18
90  19
95  20
```

Comment: would this be the same as just creating an array, and passing it in to the dataframe as the index?

Comment: I might just add that per the documentation, leaving it out will create it with steps of 1 automatically

Comment: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=240, step=1) \n
months                object  \n
Event Probability     object
Probability %        float64
dtype: object                                                                                                                                      can you please tell me how to limit only the months column ?