# How to correctly index and split a panda dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

[this is what my dataset looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MmJH.png)
Darts time series object requires indexing. I am trying to index the field 'cases' and 'rain'.

I did try time-based indexing using:
(Note: "train_test_split" is from the sklearn model of scikit_learn package)

```
csv_file = 'data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

# Assuming the index has two columns: 'Year' and 'Week'
df['Year_Week'] = df['Year'].astype(str) + '-' + df['Week'].astype(str)

# Convert the 'Year_Week' column to a datetime format with Sunday as the start of the week
df['Year_Week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year_Week'] + '-0', format='%Y-%U-%w')

# Set 'Year_Week' as the index of the DataFrame
df.set_index('Year_Week', inplace=True)

# Now, DataFrame has a datetime index based on the 'Year' and 'Week' columns

# Split data into train and test sets
train_size = 0.8
test_size = 0.2

train_data, test_data = train_test_split(df, train_size=train_size, test_size=test_size)

# Create Darts TimeSeries objects for training and testing data
train_series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(train_data[['Cases']], freq='W')
test_series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(test_data[['Cases']], freq='W')
train_covariate_series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(train_data[['Rain']], freq='W')
test_covariate_series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(test_data[['Rain']], freq='W')
```

However, when I run `print(len(test_series))` or `print(len(train_series))`, it returns the total number of rows in the original `df`.

I have also tried normal integer indexing but can't quite figure out how to make it work.

```
# Split data into train and test sets
train_size = 0.8
test_size = 0.2
random_state = 42

train_data, test_data = train_test_split(df, train_size=train_size, test_size=test_size, random_state=random_state)

# Create Darts TimeSeries objects with a simple integer index
train_series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(train_data, value_cols=['Cases'])
test_series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(test_data, value_cols=['Cases'])
train_covariate_series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(train_data, value_cols=['Rain'])
test_covariate_series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(test_data, value_cols=['Rain'])
```

which resulted in

```
    raise ValueError(message)
ValueError: Could not convert integer index to a pd.RangeIndex. Found non-unique step sizes/frequencies: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}. If any of those is the actual frequency, try passing it with fill_missing_dates=True and freq=your_frequency
```

along with some other errors.

How do I correctly index and split the dataframe?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You may want to skip the read_csv part and directly print df.head().to_dict() for us. Data is best shared as [text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). Good practices: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: This might help - range index constructor https://stackoverflow.com/q/44452751/12846804

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need:

```
train_data, test_data = train_test_split(df, train_size=train_size, test_size=test_size, shuffle=False)
```

Function train_test_split from scikit-learn.model_selection shuffles the data before sampling. You shouldn't do that when working with time series.

You got that wrong result because when you created darts timeseries with freq='week', it added rows with .nan values for each week inbetween the time of your samples that did not contain an explicit value.